# How to filter rooms by date range in React, Node.js, and Mongoose?"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I am trying to create a functionality to filter rooms by date range in [React], [Node.js], and [Mongoose]. I have a list of rooms and I want to be able to filter them based on the check-in and check-out dates selected by the user.

I have a scenario where I have 5 rooms for rent (Room 1, Room 2, Room 3, Room 4, and Room 5), and I need to implement date range filtering for room availability. Here's the booking information:

Room 1 is booked from 11/10/23 to 12/10/23 and from 13/10/2023 to 14/10/2023.
Room 2 is booked from 11/10/2023 to 12/10/2023.
Room 3 is booked from 13/10/2023 to 14/10/2023.
Room 4 is booked from 12/10/2023 to 15/10/2023.
When a user selects a date range, such as 11/10/23 to 12/10/23, I want to hide Room 1, Room 2, and Room 4 (as they are not available for booking) and display Room 3 and Room 5 (which are available for booking).

•when I select 11/10/2023 to 12/10/2023   room 1, room 2 get hide but room 4 not hide as room 4 check-in date is same as room 1 & room 2 check-out date, so it should get hide.

•when I select 13/10/2023 to 14/10/2023   room 3 not hide, but logic wise it should get hide.

Please help me
I am a beginner developer and I am stuck on a problem for the last 4 days. I am trying to create a functionality to filter rooms by date range in [React], [Node.js],[antd date picker] and [Mongoose].
I really appreciate the kind and guided help towards me.
thank you so much in advance.

my Twitter - https://twitter.com/PranjalChaura20

I've implemented the date range filtering at fronted using [React.js], [JavaScript] and the [Moment.js] library. Here's my current code fonted code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Room from '../components/Room.js';
import 'antd/dist/reset.css';
import moment from 'moment';
import { DatePicker } from 'antd';
const { RangePicker } = DatePicker;

function Home() {
  // State variables
  const [rooms, setRooms] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(); // Initialize to false
  const [error, setError] = useState(); // Initialize to false
  const [checkInDate, setCheckInDate] = useState();
  const [checkOutDate, setCheckOutDate] = useState();
  const [duplicateRooms, setDuplicateRooms] = useState([]);

  // Fetch room data on component mount
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        setLoading(true); // Set loading to true while fetching
        const response = await axios.get('/api/rooms/getallrooms');

        const data = response.data;
        
        
        setRooms(data);
        setDuplicateRooms(data);
        setLoading(false); // Set loading back to false after fetching
      } catch (error) {
        setError(true); // Set error to true in case of an error
        console.log(error);
        setLoading(false); // Set loading back to false
      }
    };

    fetchData(); // Call the async function to fetch data
  }, []);




  //Function to handle date range filtering
  function filterByDate(dates) {
    if (dates && dates.length === 2) {
      const checkInDateObj = new Date(dates[0]);
      const checkOutDateObj = new Date(dates[1]);

      const checkInFormatted = moment(checkInDateObj).format('DD-MM-YYYY');
      const checkOutFormatted = moment(checkOutDateObj).format('DD-MM-YYYY');


      setCheckInDate(checkInFormatted);
      setCheckOutDate(checkOutFormatted);


      var tempRooms = [];
      var availability = false;
      for (const rooms of duplicateRooms) {
        if (rooms.currentBooking.length > 0) {
          for (const bookings of rooms.currentBooking) {
            if (
              !(
                moment(checkInFormatted).isBetween(
                  bookings.checkInDate._i,
                  bookings.checkOutDate._i,
                  '[]'
                ) &&
                moment(checkOutFormatted).isBetween(
                  bookings.checkInDate._i,
                  bookings.checkOutDate._i,
                  '[]'
                )
              ) &&
              (
                checkInFormatted !== bookings.checkInDate._i &&
                checkInFormatted !== bookings.checkOutDate._i &&
                checkOutFormatted !== bookings.checkInDate._i &&
                checkOutFormatted !== bookings.checkOutDate._i
              )
            ) {
              availability = true;
            }
          }
        }

        if (availability === true || rooms.currentBooking.length === 0) {

          tempRooms.push(rooms);

        }

        setRooms(tempRooms);
      }
    }
  }





  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row mt-5">
        <div className="col-md-3">
          {/* Date range picker */}
          <RangePicker format="DD-MM-YYYY" onChange={filterByDate} />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="row justify-content-center mt-5">
        {/* Conditionally render based on loading and error */}
        {loading ? (
          <h1>Loading.........</h1>
        ) : error ? (
          <h1>Error.....</h1>
        ) : (
          rooms.map((room) => (
            <div className="col-md-9 mt-2" key={room._id}>
              {/* Pass room data and date information to Room component */}

              <Room
                room={room}
                checkInDate={checkInDate}

                checkOutDate={checkOutDate}
              />
            </div>
          ))
        )}
      </div>

    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Below is my roomModel:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const roomSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true 
    },
    maxcount: {
      type: Number,
      required: true
    },
    
rentperday: {
      type: Number,
      required: true
    },
    imgUrl: [
      {
        type: String 
      }
    ],
    currentBooking: [],
    type: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

const roomModel = mongoose.model('rooms', roomSchema); 

export default roomModel;
```